# CodeIgniter 3 session security

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a question about security in netbeans. Generally I have problems understanding the session. I think the session value user can change and when my code view is this:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('uid', $result['uid']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('uname', $result['uname']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('uemail', $result['uemail']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('privilages', $result['privilages']);
```

I send to session privates data like userid or privileges. It is possible to change value of session and if is possible, how I can make my system more secure?

Comment: Session data can change on the server side, the user can just change the session id that matches these values

Comment: that is it not is possible to have access to admin panel when user don't have permission?

Comment: 0700 for file permission is good for sessions

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What is your concern about sessions?

Comment: the point is that I'm scared that if the session save important data whether the user can change it. If this is not to say that I can save permissions